# True and false and true

Tags: code-golf

Challenge is to write a function/program which outputs a [truthy or falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/52210) value alternately each time you call it. No input.

It can start with either true or false.

Comment: I would recommend posting your challenges to the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) first for feedback next time.

Comment: Can it be a full program instead of a function?

Comment: Yes, full programs are allowed

Comment: So if I open an entirely clean environment to run the program, it should print  "False" instead of "True" (or vice versa)? Or can you require it be repeatedly run in the same context? (i.e. "f()\nf()" prints "True\nFalse")

Comment: Same context, not a clean environment

Comment: Allowing programs may be problematic. What can be assumed between program executions? Can it be assumed that any variables created by the program will be seen by the next execution? More generally, to which extent is "state" preserve between executions?

Comment: By allowing full programs I meant for calling the function multiple times

Comment: May I assume that nothing is happening between subsequent calls?

Comment: Yes, nothing in between calls

Comment: I think you're starting to give people too much liberty. *Nothing between calls* is a bit iffy for tacit languages (including stack-based ones), as you can operate on the previous return value for free. If full programs are valid or not is also unclear at this point. You should clarify these things in the question.

Comment: Most answers here rely on externals or globals which could change between calls.

Comment: Curiously, on the day this challenge was posted, Mathematica released, in v. 11.1, the function, `PersistentValue`, which supports values that persist between sessions.  (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PersistentValue.html)

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
®¬©
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@39o3aE1h1b@P7TIGhtSeLhj@6OGOQrOiTk5OgrJ@XnJiSWpeUCso1CUWpCaWKL3HwA)

#### How it works

```
®¬©  Main link. No arguments.

®    Retrieve the value stored in the register.
 ¬   Negate it.
  ©  Copy the result to the register.
```

Comment: This looks like a distraught frog and I can't stop laughing about it.

Comment: According to [this comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113134/true-and-false-and-true/113139#comment275837_113134), `¬` might be valid as well. Dibs on the 1-byte solution in case this turns out to be allowed.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript ES6, 11 bytes

```
f=i=_=>i=!i
```

```js
f=i=_=>i=!i

console.log(f());
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If I run it again with a clean environment, it fails.

Comment: Uh... wow, ok, that works. That's really clever, actually :D

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes

```python
def f():f.n^=1;print f.n
f.n=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@SmqaQpqFplaaXF2draF1QlJlXogDkcAGxrcF/oBQXHvwfAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Cyoce</sup>

```python
def f(x=[]):x+=0,;print len(x)%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@SmqaQplFhGx2raVWhbWugY11QlJlXopCTmqdRoalq9D8tv0ghUyEzT11BXcvQwCpNQ/M/AA)

This works because the list used as (optional) argument is kept between function calls.
[It's not a bug, it's a feature](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm)

Comment: Does `def f(x=[0]):x[0]^=1;print x[0]` work?

Comment: @Neil yep, it works

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
int f=0;boolean c(){return++f%2<1;}
// OR
boolean f;boolean c(){return f=!f;}     // Thanks to @Poke
```

Old answer: `int f=0;boolean c(){return(f^=1)<1;}`

Extremely short for a Java 7 answer. :D (Although still the longest of all submissions of course)

**Explanation:**

```
int f=0;              // Integer flag on class level
boolean c(){          // Method with no parameters and a boolean return-type
  return ++f % 2 < 1  //  return whether `f` modulo 2 is 0 (but increase `f` first)
}                     // End of method
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#xY1BCsIwFET3PcVshJRCULexR@iqS3GR1lQCyU9JfhUpOXuMXsLVwJvHTJmdTgnD3gCWGEt/VFMIzmjCLNo9Gt4idd1yOF9OKjdVW7fJ2RmJNdd4BnuH15bEyNHS43qDbr9rwACPHmReGESrfmh8JzZeho3lWm12JLysP3@vc5NL@QA)

```
class M{
  int f=0;boolean c(){return++f%2<1;}

  public static void main(String[] a){
    M m = new M();
    System.out.println(m.c());
    System.out.println(m.c());
    System.out.println(m.c());
    System.out.println(m.c());
    System.out.println(m.c());
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
true
false
true
false
```

Comment: `boolean f;boolean c(){return f=!f;}` is also 35 bytes

Comment: @Poke Oops, I've been overthinking it apparently..

Comment: Your answer works nicely too :] The bytecount of `boolean` is enough to dissuade me in a lot of cases, haha

Comment: @Poke Exactly, that's why I had rejected `boolean` from a possible solution right away for this challenge. ;)

Answer (score 2):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 6 bytes

```
{T!:T}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@18domgVUvvfys2ayw0G/gMA)

Pushes `T` (initially `0`, falsy), negates it (toggling between `1`, truthy, and `0`), stores the result in `T` for the next invocation and leaves it on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 4 bytes

```
i=~i
```

`i` is initially `sqrt(-1)`. Everything that's not `0` is considered `true` in Octave (note, this doesn't work in MATLAB).

`i=~i` assigns `not(true)` to `i`, making it `false`, The next iteration it will be `false` again.

This is a full program, that can be called using the file name. Example from [octave-online](http://octave-online.net/) with a file name called `inverter.m`:

```
octave:1> source("inverter.m")
i = 0
octave:1> source("inverter.m")
i =  1
octave:1> source("inverter.m")
i = 0
octave:1> source("inverter.m")
i =  1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes

```python
def f(x=[]):x+=print(len(x)&1),
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@5@SmqaQplFhGx2raVWhbVtQlJlXopGTmqdRoalmqKnzP01DkwsP/g8A)

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>39</s> <s>30</s> <s>26</s> <s>19</s> 18 Bytes

Using a Macro now

```
i;
#define f i++%2
```

Thanks for the help i=!i

<s>i;f(){return i=!i;}</s>

<s>i;f(){return i++?i=0,1:0;}</s>

<s>i;f(){putchar(i++?i=0,70:84);}</s>

<s>f(){static i=0;putchar(i++?i=0,70:84);}</s>

```
main()
{
    putchar(48+f);puts("");
    putchar(48+f);puts("");
    putchar(48+f);puts("");
    putchar(48+f);puts("");
}
```

Output

```
0
1
0
1
```

Comment: You could change the return to `i=!i` [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@59pnaahWV2UWlJalKeQaauYaV37PzcxM09Dk6uaSwEICkpLkjMSizRMLLSBKjWtgfxiDSUlTWsaytb@BwA)

Comment: `i;f(){return++i%2;}` is shorter [**19 bytes**] (based on my Java 7 answer). [Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@59pnaahWV2UWlJalKetnalqZF37PzcxM09Dk6uaSwEICkpLkjMSizRMLLSBKjWtgfxiDSUlTWsaytb@BwA)

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 12 bytes

Either of these works:

```
(x=x=!=1>0)&
(x=x===0>1)&
```

I would love to express the `True` or `False` at the end using only `x` and `=` or maybe `!` as well, but unfortunately, that gets longer.

In the notebook environment we can also use this 8-byte solution:

```
%=!=1>0&
```

But it only works if the call to the function is the only thing on its line and there are no other function calls in between, so I won't count this one.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>15 14</s> 12 bytes

```
->{0>$.^=-1}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>31</s> 25 bytes

*Thanks to user63956 for golfing 6 bytes*

```php
function(){echo$_GET^=1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyChQ4OJSSVOwVfifVpqXXJKZn6ehWZ2anJGvEu/uGhJna2hd@98aqEJDEyf5HwA)

This is an anonymous function.

Comment: You can use superglobal variables: `function(){echo$_GET^=1;}`.

Comment: @user63956 Weird, I tried it with $argv and $argc and it didn't work so I didn't even try $_GET. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 11 bytes

```bash
f()((n^=1))
```

Output is via the function's status code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#PcmxCoAgEADQWb/ikAZvCdwCif6kCL1DQRQ0p@jbbaq3vsEatc77ahAHlwoHxAy3meflseCLFJGBLVyBshSCXCigWneOWgM9baikoNToPz5j6pW@4yh9yTRe)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 25 bytes

```bash
sed -i y/TF/FT/ $0
echo T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S03OyFdQ/1@cmqKgm6lQqR/ipu8Woq@gYsCVCpIJ@a9uV5KaW2CdlFicoUCY9R8A)

This is a full program. You must have write access to the file in addition to execute.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 32 bytes

Not competing because ints aren't truth and false values in Java and an  answer like that already exists.

```
int a;int f(){return a=a>0?0:1;}
```

Ungolfed(barely anything to ungolf):

```
int a;
int f() {
    return a = a > 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, returning `0` or `1` isn't considered a [truthy/falsey value in Java](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/52210). Also, if it would have been, this would be shorter: `int a;int f(){return++f%2;}` (**27 bytes**)

Comment: Instead of making it non-completing, can you edit to output truthy and falsy values?

Comment: @Riker An answer like this already exists

Comment: You're allowed to post an identical answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Applescript, 25

```applescript
property i:0
set i to 1-i
```

Applescript properties are persistent.  The result of the last assignment is implicitly given as the program result.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 52 bytes

```
import Control.Monad.State
execState(modify not)True
```

This uses the State monad to store a boolean value which is initially set to `True`. Additional calls must also run within the State monad, e.g.

```
 execState(modify not>>modify not>>modify not)True
```

which evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 25 bytes

```
var b=8<9
def f={b= !b;b}
```

#### Explanation:

```
var b = 8 < 9 // define a variable b as false
def f = {     // define a function f wothout parameters
  b = !b      // invert the state of b
  b           // return b
}
```

There needs to be a space in `b= !b`, so scala doesn't want to invoke the method `=!` on b, which doesn't exists.